# Limit filesize, when redirecting console output to file?

Tags: windows, redirect, console, limit, filesize

I am looking for a solution, to limit the size of the file,
when redirecting console output to a logfile.

Is there any existing solution?

```
REM limit logfile.txt to x MB
command > logfile.txt
```

Comment: Maybe pipe the output to a custom program which truncates it?

Comment: Currently working on it, thought there may be a native solution for that

Comment: On Linux you could use `cut`, but on Windows I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is too late, but i hope that it may help someone else

What i did is after executing my main command and if it was a success i execute a script to check the log file size ...

This can be achieved using

```
&& execute_your_filzsize_limit_check_script_or_program
```

for exemple

```
command > logfile.txt && filesize_check.exe
```